# feature versioning in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-feature

I've followed following link to implement feature versioning:
http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/using-the-featureupgrading-event-to-upgrade-features-sharepoint-2010/

I am new to sharepoint and the requirement is to show the versions of features in my site. Is it possible?
I am not able to see the version anywhere in the site. I can see appropriate version in the feature.xml file in feature folder of 14 hive. Just want to know that is it possible to see the versions of each deploy in sharepoint site also?If yes then where can I see it?

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If custom solution fits your requirement then you can try following ways to find activated feature versions.

1. Use SPFarm.FeatureDefinitions

to get all activated features in the Farm -

```
SPFeatureDefinitionCollection farmFeatures = SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions;
foreach (SPFeatureDefinition feature in farmFeatures)
{
....
}
```

1. To find a version of a particular feature

   ```
   var spFarm = SPFarm.Local;
   System.Version version = spFarm.FeatureDefinitions["YourFeatureName"].Version;
   ```
2. Use SPContext.Current.SiteFeatures or SPContext.Current.Site.Features

   ```
   var siteFeatures= SPContext.Current.SiteFeatures;
   foreach (SPFeature sf in siteFeatures)
   ```

   {

   variable = sf.Definition.DisplayName;

   ```
   variable = sf.Definition.Version.ToString();
   }
   ```

4 Use SPContext.Current.WebFeatures or SPContext.Current.Web.Features

```
var webFeatures= SPContext.Current.WebFeatures;

foreach (SPFeature webFtr in webFeatures)
{
variable= webFtr.Definition.DisplayName;
variable= webFtr.Definition.Version.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to see this in Central Admin or Site Settings. The point is to abstract away versioning from users. Users just know that a specific feature is available, not what version. I agree that it would be nice to actually be able to see this info without having to write a custom solution.

Comment: Yeah it would be great if user can have a list of feature versions. Anyway, I'll have to manage it using custom code.